# C# Task.WhenAll should we call await or .Result and any side effects?

Tags: c#, async-await

We have code like this and seem to get inconstant results(meaning that sometimes no results are returned, they are all 0 counts!) when called in production. I was wondering would the **await** calls after the **WaitAll** causes issues as it seems like we should maybe be calling `.Result`?

For example when we call the below, should we be calling .Result instead.

```
Destinations = await arrivalsDestinations,
```

After doing the Task.WhenAll

Example code here:

```
var inHouseDestinations = GetDestinationPax(destinations, PaxPassengerLocation.InHouse, destinationFacet);
var arrivalsDestinations = GetDestinationPax(destinations, PaxPassengerLocation.Arrivals, destinationFacet);
var arrivalsTomorrowDestinations = GetDestinationPax(destinations, PaxPassengerLocation.ArrivalsTomorrow, destinationFacet);
var departuresDestinations = GetDestinationPax(destinations, PaxPassengerLocation.Departures, destinationFacet);

await Task.WhenAll(
        inHouseDestinations, arrivalsDestinations, arrivalsTomorrowDestinations, departuresDestinations);

var arrivalsSummary = new PaxDataSummary()
{
    PassengerLocation = PaxPassengerLocation.Arrivals,
    Destinations = await arrivalsDestinations,
    Resorts = await arrivalsResorts,
    Properties = await arrivalsProperties
};
```

Comment: await calls after the WaitAll or WhenAll? What does inconstant mean?

Comment: The results for awaiting multiple tasks that all return the same type (in your example, I assume they all return `Destinations`) are returned from the `await Task.WhenAll()` in an array: `Destination[] destinations = await Task.WhenAll(inHouseDestinations, ...)`. A think you should be using the return values that way.

Comment: What do you mean @MatthewWatson? return value which way?

Comment: Generally you want to avoid calling `.Result` at the best of times.  Not only does it defeat the purpose of `Task` but, depending on the application type (I'm looking at you ASP.NET classic). you are at risk of encountering a **thread deadlock!**  _[Goodness, tell me more...](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)_

Comment: The results have supposedly all be completed in the WhenAll so it seems that its ok to still call await after the fact and not call .Result.

Comment: @Andrew I'm saying that the results of the tasks are ALREADY returned in an array as the return value from `Task.WhenAll()` so you can use the results from that array instead of calling `await` or `.Result` again. (Assuming that the tasks all return the same result type)

Comment: Ok thanks @MatthewWatson, we would not want to dump all results, we would need separate ones, this would mean that we have to just get each result set from array index e.g. [0], [1]...etc!?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I note that you're only actually using the results from `arrivalsDestinations` in your sample code. Is that correct, or is that just a transcription error?

Comment: Yes correct there was more blocks of other calls and I just pulled one block out. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Code that you have with await more correct )You can use both variant, but .Result blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.

Comment: Since it first went thourgh WhenAll, calling `.Result` won't block more or less than using await. The real difference is in how Exceptions are handled: `await` will unwrap the potential `AggregateException` while `.Result` will return it as-is.